# Pandas: To create a new column based on two column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Learning column comparison. 
How to create a new column based on two columns?

I can do two conditions fruit or vegetable. But for the third condition, couldn’t do. :(

```
df
    basket1     basket2
0   fruit       fruit
1   vegetable   vegetable 
2   vegetable   both
3   fruit       both
```

The result

Newdf

```
    basket1    basket2    total
0   fruit      fruit      fruit
1   vegetable  vegetable  vegetable  
2   vegetable  both       Unknown
3   fruit      both      fruit
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking or trying to do. Did you try some code that got this result? Do you intend for the logic to produce `Unknown` when `vegetable` and `both` are in the other columns?

Comment: Yes i want to separate vegetable both and fruit both to two separate words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

Revisiting this, `DataFrame.apply` is slow AF. Let's look at some other options and then compare.

### Other options to `DataFrame.apply`

1. `numpy.where`

This method can be applied when we only have two options. In your case, this is true as we return `df.a` when `df.a == df.b` or `df.a == 'fruit' and df.b == 'both'`. The syntax is `np.where(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)`.

```
In [42]: df['np_where'] = np.where(
    ...:     ((df.a == df.b) | ((df.a == 'fruit') & (df.b == 'both'))),
    ...:     df.a,
    ...:     'Unknown'
    ...: )
```

2. `numpy.select`

You would use this option if you had multiple conditions. The syntax for this is `np.select(condition, values, default)` where `default` is an optional parameter.

```
In [43]: conditions = df.a == df.b, (df.a == 'fruit') & (df.b == 'both')

In [44]: choices = df['a'], df['a']

In [45]: df['np_select'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Unknown')
```

Note that for the purposes of demonstration I have created two conditions even if the outcomes yield the same result.

### Comparing the options

As you can see, all three methods have the same outcome.

```
In [47]: df
Out[47]:
           a          b   np_where  np_select   df_apply
0      fruit      fruit      fruit      fruit      fruit
1  vegetable  vegetable  vegetable  vegetable  vegetable
2  vegetable       both    Unknown    Unknown    Unknown
3      fruit       both      fruit      fruit      fruit
```

But how do they compare in terms of speed? To check this, let's create a newer, larger `DataFrame`. We're doing this to see how our options perform with larger amounts of data.

```
In [48]: df_large = pd.DataFrame({
    ...:     'a': np.random.choice(['fruit', 'vegetable'], size=1_000_000),
    ...:     'b': np.random.choice(['fruit', 'vegetable', 'both'], size=1_000_000)
    ...: })

In [49]: %timeit df_large['np_where'] = np.where(((df_large.a == df_large.b) | ((df_large.a == 'fruit')
    ...:  & (df_large.b == 'both'))), df_large.a, 'Unknown')
379 ms ± 64.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [50]: %timeit df_large['np_select'] = np.select(((df_large.a == df_large.b), ((df_large.a == 'fruit'
    ...: ) & (df_large.b == 'both'))), (df_large.a, df_large.a), default='Unknown')
580 ms ± 101 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [51]: %timeit df_large['df_apply'] = df_large.apply(total, axis=1)
40.5 s ± 6 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Wow! As you can see `DataFrame.apply` is *much* slower than our other two options and `np.where` edges out `np.select`.

### Conclusions

- Use `np.where` if you have only two choices
- Use `np.select` if you have multiple choices
- Don't use `DataFrame.apply` (especially for large data sets)!

### Resources

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19913845/5491375
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31173785/5491375 (has some fast options if you're only interested in a single column)

---

Create your own function and use `DataFrame.apply`

```
In [104]: def total(r):
     ...:     if r.a == r.b:
     ...:         return r.a
     ...:     elif (r.a == 'fruit') and (r.b == 'both'):
     ...:         return r.a
     ...:     return 'Unknown'
     ...:

In [105]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['fruit', 'vegetable', 'vegetable', 'fruit'], 'b': ['fruit', 'vegetable', 'both', 'both']})

In [106]: df
Out[106]:
           a          b
0      fruit      fruit
1  vegetable  vegetable
2  vegetable       both
3      fruit       both

In [107]: df['total'] = df.apply(total, axis=1)

In [108]: df
Out[108]:
           a          b      total
0      fruit      fruit      fruit
1  vegetable  vegetable  vegetable
2  vegetable       both    Unknown
3      fruit       both      fruit
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df["total"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.a if (x.a == x.b) or ((x.a == 'fruit') and (x.b == 'both')) else 'Unkonwn', axis = 1)
```

Output

```
           a          b      total
0      fruit      fruit      fruit
1  vegetable  vegetable  vegetable
2  vegetable       both    Unkonwn
3      fruit       both      fruit
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's solution using `np.select`

```
df['total'] = np.select([df['a']==df['b'], (df['a']=='fruit')&(df['b']=='both')], [df['a'], 'fruit'], 'Unkown')
```

Output:

```
    a          b           total
0   fruit      fruit       fruit
1   vegetable  vegetable   vegetable
2   vegetable  both        Unknown 
3   fruit      both        fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

> data.csv

```
basket1,basket2
fruit,fruit
vegetable,vegetable
vegetable,both
fruit,both
```

> code.py

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    if df.at[i, 'basket1'] == df.at[i, 'basket2']:
        df.at[i, 'total'] = df.at[i, 'basket1']
    else:
        df.at[i, 'total'] = 'something else'
```

Output:

```
     basket1    basket2           total
0      fruit      fruit           fruit
1  vegetable  vegetable       vegetable
2  vegetable       both  something else
3      fruit       both  something else
```